# When moving a WordPress installation to a new server, why do I have to update each post before content shows?

Tags: posts, migration, import, export

The site URL (www.example.com) hasn't changed.  So I exported the `wp_posts` table from my old shared hosting server database and imported it into a new WordPress installation on my new dedicated server.

I set the permalink structure in the WordPress installation on the new server to be `http://www.example.com/%postname%/`, the same as on the old shared hosting server.

So when I go to an a blog post such as `http://www.example.com/blog-post`, nothing displays.  I have to go into the admin panel's "Edit" post functionality and then click "Update" before the original post content shows up.

Why might this be?  All the data values including the guid are the same...

Comment: You imported just the single table into another WordPress DB?  THAT is the problem.  Post IDs are unique between sites and you likely caused a massive corruption in the site on the new server.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.  Hmm...can you elaborate a bit? what is the mechanism to ensure that post id's are unique between sites?  And then how do I import the post content such that I don't cause corruption?  I'm a bit fuzzy on the workings of wordpress - I assumed post id's were unique across the database, not between sites.  Hence, if I imported post id's into a blank wp_posts table, it would have been fine

Comment: I would avoid working with individual tables unless absolutely necessary.  If the task is to move a site to a new server, you are in luck as this is very simple:   https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Keeping_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

Comment: Thanks...I moved the wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, and wp_term_taxonomy in addition to the wp_posts table and now everything appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

jdm2112 identified the issue as being caused by missing tables as part of the migration process within the comments for the original question:

> You imported just the single table into another WordPress DB? THAT is
>   the problem. Post IDs are unique between sites... I would avoid
>   working with individual tables unless absolutely necessary

After migrating the rest of the tables, Nona reports that this issue has been resolved:

> Thanks... I moved the `wp_terms`, `wp_term_relationships`, and
>   `wp_term_taxonomy` in addition to the `wp_posts` table and now
>   everything appears to work.